# Wordpress: Wrong datatype for second argument?

Tags: php, wordpress, video-thumbnails

I got this error yesterday after upgrading wordpress. It's pointing to one of my plugins:

> Warning: in_array()
>   [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype
>   for second argument in
>   /home/healt134/public_html/wp-content/plugins/video-thumbnails/video-thumbnails.php
>   on line 402
>
> ```
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> ```
>
> (output started at
>   /home/healt134/public_html/wp-content/plugins/video-thumbnails/video-thumbnails.php:402)
>   in
>   /home/healt134/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 897

I looked at the code in 402 (marked with asterisks) but I don't see a problem or excess white-space there. Anyone know what I might be able to do to stop this error?

```
    function save_video_thumbnail( $post ){
        $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
        $video_thumbnails_post_types = get_option('video_thumbnails_post_types');
***     if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return null;
        } else {
            // Check that Video Thumbnails are enabled for current post type
            if (in_array($post_type, $video_thumbnails_post_types) OR $post_type == $video_thumbnails_post_types) {
                get_video_thumbnail($post->ID);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what's on pluggable.php on line 897?  Normally I see this error when you're trying to start a session when a session is already started (maybe check the get_option function too)

Comment: @DaOgre The output started is just the warning from the incorrect use of `in_array()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're off by a couple of lines there, try 4 lines lower. My guess is `$video_thumbnails_post_types` is not an array.

From the second condition in that `if` statement, it looks like `$video_thumbnails_post_types` may be a scalar (string, int, etc). If you're up to it, modify the code to be

```
if (in_array($post_type, (array) $video_thumbnails_post_types)
    || $post_type == $video_thumbnails_post_types)
```

Comment: @Kayle I'd also consider sending a message to the plugin developer and link them to your question